# Updating the JSON.stringify(canvas); with latest canvas changes

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to be able to log and capture my Fabric.js `canvas` with its latest changes. Currently, with `console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));` I am able to see that it pushes the background color for example, but not anything else like the drawings that I add, etc.

Is this possible and if so how might I accomplish this?

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  centeredScaling: true,
  isDrawingMode: true
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
```

```css
body {
}

canvas {
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

*An Aside:*

**My end goal is to eventually be able to load this JSON back onto the canvas later, so I want to learn how to get the latest objects into the JSON to start.**  Am I on the right track or am I misunderstanding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't `JSON.stringify` such a complex object - when I say you can't, I mean, you're not getting a JSON (string) that you can `JSON.parse` later to recreate the original object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#toJSON) to make a JSON of canvas and load it again using [loadFromJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#loadFromJSON).

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  centeredScaling: true,
  isDrawingMode: true
});

var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');

function loadOnCanvas(){
 var json = canvas.toJSON();
 console.log(json)
 canvas1.loadFromJSON(json,canvas1.renderAll.bind(canvas1));
}
```

```css
body {
}

canvas {
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 5px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='loadOnCanvas()'>Load</button>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas><br>
<canvas id="canvas1" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! A follow-up question: Would you care to elaborate on what any method(s) of saving the JSON might be? I'd like to be able to either save the JSON to my computer or server and then restore it from my computer or server. Is this realistic? What do you think I should be looking to do next in order to accomplish a JSON saver/loader, like in [the Fabric.js example here](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink)? Cheers.

Comment: @codeforever save in a server, while loading in client load that json